# É possível recuperar outros campos além do da chave estrangeira?

Tags: php, mysql

A dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu possuo essas duas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que carro_id é chave estrangeira na tabela "pessoa"... Se eu quiser trazer uma query como por exemplo:

"Nome da Pessoa, Nascimento, Marca do Carro e Ano do carro" Eu consigo? Visto que pela relação eu só tenho a coluna ID referenciada na tabela pessoa...

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo como

```
select Pessoa.Nome, Carro.Marca from Pessoa 
    inner join Carro
       on Pessoa.Carro_id = Carro.Carro_id
```

?

Comment: Sim, era isso mesmo! Obrigado!